# Create itunes sandbox tester programmatically for automated testing

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We have an automated UI test for a 'new user flow' where a new user signs up for our app and completes an in-app purchase for their subscription. Each time the test runs, a new user is created in our back-end. We are currently using a single iTunes sandbox user which we created manually for this automated test. However, as we keep running the test, the receipt grows huge and it ends up being associated with multiple users. In a real situation, one iTunes account would be associated with one user in our app. In the current scenario, one iTunes account is associated with multiple users in our back-end.

We would like a way to create a sandbox user in iTunes each time the test runs, then use this sandbox user to create an account in our app for this test case. However, the only way I can find to create a sandbox user is manually.

Is there a way to programmatically create a sandbox account either through code or through our CI tool (BuddyBuild) so we can simulate a true user flow?

Comment: Strangely, apple has released the "App Store Connect API" yet this this feature is missing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spaceship to create Sandbox users from the command line.

First, you have to log in and choose your team.

More instructions on how to do so are here:
[Spaceship Home](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship)

Here's the API you can use to create Sandbox Testers:

```
Spaceship::ConnectAPI::SandboxTester.create(email: 'mail@mail.com', password:'12345678', confirm_password: '12345678', app_store_territory: 'AUT', first_name: 'Steve', last_name: 'Brule', secret_question: "the question", secret_answer: "the answer", birth_date: "1980-03-01")
```

I'm still looking into the Spaceship code to see how they internally are calling the ConnectAPI, since in the new specifications from 2020 I can't still find the creation of Sandbox users specifically.